# Store and continue the execution in try except in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to store the error message and continue the execution but when I store the error message using the except exception e:  then I am not able to continue the execution. The function stops execution if URL does not get the HTTP URL, the function gives an error if

```
url="www.boomlive.in/fact-file/did-the-race-to-5g-cause-the-coronavirus-outbreak-7404"
```

My code is

```py
def twitter_link(url):
    twitter_title=[]
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    for i in soup.find_all("p"):
        try:
           for a in i.find_all("a", href=True):
              if "twitter" in a["href"]:
                 x=a["href"]
               twitter_title.append(x)
        except Exception as e:
           twitter_title.append(str(e))
           continue  

    return twitter_title
```

My excepted output is function stores URL in list twitter_title, if there is an error then store the error message and continue the executions

Comment: Where's the code for your exception?

Comment: By default the error handling in python will continue execution if there is no explicit `return` or `break` statement.

Comment: "www.boomlive.in..." is not a  URL. `requests.get()` will fail with this argument. It should start with "http://"

Comment: @BruceWayne I added the code

Comment: @pciunkiewicz how to resolve this kind issue

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov yes I am running this function on 2103 URL, that's why I wanted to catch the exception and store it

Answer (score 1):

The function stops executing because the exception is thrown by `requests.get(url)` and that call is not inside the try-block.